# HTML/CSS Fill div with color from right to left and left to right

Tags: html, css, user-interface, pdf, web

I'm trying to make my own bar chart which i imported it to pdf using Dom PDF. i have minus number on my result so i need to fill my bar from right to left. This is my current code right now

```
<td width="400px">
                <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:10px;">
                    <div
                        style="width:50%;display:inline-block;text-align:right">
                        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-large"
                            style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:2px;text-align:right;">
                            <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-large"
                                style="width:40%;text-align:right;float:right">0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        style="width:50%;display:inline-block;text-align:right">
                        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-large"
                            style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:2px;text-align:left">
                            <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-large"
                                style="width:50%;text-align:center;">{{$sjt}}</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

</td>
```

and the result goes like this.
[image: result bar]

Is it possible to achieve that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<td width="400px">
  <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:10px;">
    <div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;text-align:right">
      <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-large" style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:2px;text-align:right;">
        <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-large" style="width:40%;text-align:right;float:right">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;text-align:right">
      <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-large" style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top:2px;text-align:left;display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;">
        <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-large" style="width:50%;text-align:center;">{{$sjt}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Is this what you were looking for?
[image]

Comment: i want to display it side by side, one side from right to left and the other from left to right. Each one is 50% side, so it will fill 100% display on my div

Comment: I changed both the inline-blocks to inline and they're displaying next to each other.
https://codepen.io/Mikolertesx/pen/poNvjXB

I also had to change the td to a div, since Codepen seems to ignore it if it's not inside a table.

(The reason for inline and inline-block behaving differently is something I don't understand well).